# How to use returning value in PostgreSQL query

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

PostgreSQL 9.6.

I want to use returning value at the same query, but later, something like this:

```
WITH new_track AS (
    INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time) 
    VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') RETURNING track
)

SELECT * FROM eco.new_tracks WHERE track = (SELECT track from new_track);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RETURNING *`:

```
WITH new_track AS (
    INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time) 
    VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM new_track;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8d2955e18a71c98da6d553c13a727af4)**

**EDIT:**

> *My bad. The second table is another one, please look at updated version*

```
WITH new_track AS (
    INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time) 
    VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') RETURNING id
)
SELECT * FROM eco.new_tracks t
WHERE t.col_name IN (SELECT id FROM new_track);
```

Comment: My bad. The second table is another one, please look at updated version